# Equivalence of "The Unexpected Hanging" and "The Two Generals"

Tags: logic, paradoxes, provability

The "Unexpected Hanging Paradox" is a situation in which a prediction is successfully made, even though a logical proof indicates that it couldn't possibly happen.

> A judge tells a condemned prisoner that he will be hanged at noon on one weekday in the following week but that the execution will be a surprise to the prisoner.
>   He will not know the day of the hanging until the executioner knocks on his cell door at noon that day.
>
> Having reflected on his sentence, the prisoner draws the conclusion that he will escape from the hanging.
>   His reasoning is in several parts.
>   He begins by concluding that the "surprise hanging" can't be on Friday, as if he hasn't been hanged by Thursday, there is only one day left - and so it won't be a surprise if he's hanged on Friday.
>   Since the judge's sentence stipulated that the hanging would be a surprise to him, he concludes it cannot occur on Friday.
>
> He then reasons that the surprise hanging cannot be on Thursday either, because Friday has already been eliminated and if he hasn't been hanged by Wednesday noon, the hanging must occur on Thursday, making a Thursday hanging not a surprise either.
>   By similar reasoning, he concludes that the hanging can also not occur on Wednesday, Tuesday or Monday.
>   Joyfully he retires to his cell confident that the hanging will not occur at all.
>
> — [Unexpected hanging paradox - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexpected_hanging_paradox#Description_of_the_paradox)

---

The "Two Generals Problem" is a situation in which two generals agree on a time to attack when the only means of communication is unreliable (i.e. a message might not get through), even though a logical proof indicates that it can't possibly be done.

> The Two Generals' Problem was the first computer communication problem to be proved to be unsolvable.
>   …
>   The first general may start by sending a message "Attack at 0900 on August 4." However, once dispatched, the first general has no idea whether or not the messenger got through. This uncertainty may lead the first general to hesitate to attack due to the risk of being the sole attacker.
>
> To be sure, the second general may send a confirmation back to the first: "I received your message and will attack at 0900 on August 4." However, the messenger carrying the confirmation could face capture and the second general may hesitate, knowing that the first might hold back without the confirmation.
>
> Further confirmations may seem like a solution—let the first general send a second confirmation: "I received your confirmation of the planned attack at 0900 on August 4."
>   However, this new messenger from the first general is liable to be captured, too.
>   Thus it quickly becomes evident that no matter how many rounds of confirmation are made, there is no way to guarantee the second requirement that each general be sure the other has agreed to the attack plan.
>   Both generals will always be left wondering whether their last messenger got through.
>
> — [Two Generals' Problem - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals'_Problem#Illustrating_the_problem)

---

In theory, the logical conclusions are that the prisoner cannot be surprised and that the generals cannot confirm the time.

But in practice, it is quite the opposite.

The prisoner really *is* surprised when he is hanged on Wednesday.

And if even only a few messages get through, the Generals *can* agree on a time.
Each message is numbered, and is resent (with the same ID number) if acknowledgement is not received within a predetermined time.
Additional messages are sent at regular intervals up until the time of the attack, but only after the previous message has been acknowledged.

```
- #G1-1: "attack at 0900 on August 4"
- #G2-1: "got your #1"
- #G1-2: "got your #1. carry on" [message lost]
- #G1-2: "got your #1. carry on"
- #G2-2: "got your #2. carry on"
- …
- #G1-9: "got your #8. today's the day"
- #G2-9: "got your #9. see you soon"
- …
```

The logical proof's "*Both generals will always be left wondering whether their last messenger got through.*" is still true, but it is also irrelevant.
It isn't the *last* message that's important, it's the *first* message.

Long before the 9th messages are sent, each General already knows, with certainty, that both Generals have seen message #G1-1.
If that message had *not* been received by the second General, *none* of the other messages would have existed.
But they *do*.

Just before the time of the attack, both Generals *know* that they have each seen the message, and *know* that it is appropriate for them to attack.
There is no uncertainty.

The only time this problem is "impossible to solve" is when *all* further messages are cut off, as would happen if the enemy had detected the other army and destroyed it.
But that's a problem of prematurely terminated communication, not of intermittently unreliable transmission.

---

The "Unexpected Hanging" and the "Two Generals" are very similar situations.

In each case:

- the logical reasoning is about resolving incomplete knowledge.
- the proofs start at the critical point (the execution deadline and the first message).
- one starts with certainty and propagates it backward through time to to prove there is no uncertainty, and the other starts with uncertainty and propagates it forward through time to prove that there is no certainty.
- the infinite chain of reasoning is terminated by a secondary event (the sentencing and the attack).
- at the time of the secondary event, correct decisions *can* be made, and everything resolves as it should.

In each case, the confusion is with the given proofs of impossibility, not with the procedures for how to surprise the prisoner or how to confirm the knowledge of information.

In each case, the methods of proof fail in identical ways.

---

Despite their many similarities, I have never seen these two problems discussed together.

The logical "proofs" are nearly identical in nature, and both fail to match reality for the same reason.

So, **Why is one considered an example of a "*complex paradox*", and the other an example of a "*simple unsolvable problem*"?**

Comment: You say "The only time this problem is "impossible to solve" is when all the messages are lost after the first few." But how many is "few"? If we're designing an algorithm for the generals to follow (which we definitely should, if we're considering extensions of this problem to computer networks), and the algorithm looks like "Attack if you've received the other general's $k^{\text{th}}$ message, and not otherwise", what should $k$ be? (For each of the generals separately, if necessary.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I've changed the confusing "few".  Thanks.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, thinking in terms of *k* is why the proofs fail.  It's like asking how many days before the deadline can a surprise occur.  The final decision shouldn't be based on any such *k*.  It should be made just before the time of the attack.

Comment: But just before the time of the attack, you still have to make the decision based on something. If the last message received before the attack is G1-1, do the generals attack? If the last message received before the attack is G1-2, do the generals attack? What if it's G2-1, or G2-2, or one of the others? You have to have some rule dependent on $k$ to make the decision at the end, even if your strategy is to send as many messages as possible.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, the original problem definition claims "***no matter how many** rounds of confirmation are made, there is no way to guarantee the second requirement that each general be sure the other has agreed to the attack plan*". If a hundred messages have passed back and forth since the original two messages were received, this statement is clearly not true. When the time to attack arrives, each General definitely knows that both Generals are aware of the specified time. That claim is as false as "*No matter how many days we go back, the prisoner cannot be surprised*".

Comment: "Why is one considered an example of a "complex paradox", and the other an example of a "simple unsolvable problem"?" Probably because you are relying on Wikipedia, and because the two essays were written by two different people.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the point of the two generals paradox.

It is not hard to find a threshold at which each general knows the attack time. As soon as the first message is received, this is true.

It is not hard to find a threshold at which each general knows that each general knows the attack time. As soon as the second message is received, this is true.

It is not hard to find a threshold at which each general knows that the $99^{\text{th}}$ message has been received. As soon as the $100^{\text{th}}$ message is received, this is true.

The actual impossibility is different. No matter how the generals make their decisions, one of the following two alternatives must hold:

1. There is some outcome in which one general attacks and the other general does not, or:
2. There is no outcome in which either general attacks.

If neither general is willing to tolerate outcome 1, then what it's impossible to do is to find a threshold at which each general knows **that the other general is willing to attack**.

At the end of the day, when the generals have exchanged some number of messages and we've reached the attack time, the generals *must* follow a rule such as "If I've received at least $k$ confirmation messages, I will attack; otherwise, I will not." (Of course, we can allow $k=0$ "I will always attack" or $k=\infty$ "I will never attack".) If you don't specify such a rule, then you haven't specified when the generals will act and when they won't.

Suppose that for the first general, $k=100$. Then the second general is put into an awkward position when sending back the $100^{\text{th}}$ confirmation and getting no response.

- If the second general attacks, it's possible that the second general will be attacking alone, because the $100^{\text{th}}$ confirmation was not received and so the first general got only $99$ messages.
- If the second general does not attack, it's possible that the $100^{\text{th}}$ confirmation *was* received, and so the first general attacks alone.

This is true of any threshold (for either general). So there is no threshold that either general can use to guarantee that neither general attacks alone, except for the $k=\infty$ threshold of never attacking.

You are of course free to propose other strategies for the generals to follow. They can be as silly as "attack iff you've received an odd number of confirmation messages" or something smarter and more elaborate. But the same proof works as long as your strategy is specific enough to answer the question "Will the generals attack if $k$ messages have been exchanged?" for each value of $k$.

---

Or, to put it differently: consider any example you like of a "successful" communication between the two generals: one after which they decide to attack at the end. Let's say that in this communication, $N$ messages are exchanged. ($N$ can be as large as you like, but of course it is finite.)

Now consider situations $S_0, S_1, S_2, \dots, S_N$ where situation $S_k$ is defined as follows: the first $k$ messages get through exactly as in the successful example, then afterwards no messages get through. In particular, in $S_0$, no messages get through at all.

In situation $S_0$, the generals both don't attack. In situation $S_N$, they both do. That means there must be some point at which a change happens. Either there's a case in which some general attacks alone, *or* there's a sudden switch at some $k$: in situation $S_{k-1}$, neither general attacks, and in situation $S_k$, both generals attack.

But that's impossible! Situation $S_{k-1}$ and $S_k$ are identical from the point of view of one general: the first general, if $k$ is odd, and the second general, if $k$ is even. That general can't decide to attack in situation $S_k$ but not $S_{k-1}$.

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the "paradox" argument that the prisoner can't be surprised.  There is no need for a "*k*", any more than there is a need to say that the execution can't be within "*k*" days of the deadline. Just before the attack, each General knows that both generals have agreed on the time that both generals are intending to attack. Each General made the decision to attack when he sent his first message.  After that, what possible justification (other than a false surprised-prisoner type "*k*" argument) would either General have for not attacking?

Comment: This also doesn't answer the original question as to *why* the two situations are considered fundamentally different.  It's simply stating that the Generals *need* to have a "*k*" value, even though it would be wrong to consider having one for the Prisoner, without giving any reason for this assumption.

Comment: If not without a $k$, how *do* the generals decide whether to attack or not? If "each general made his decision to attack when he sent his first message", then are you saying that the first general will attack even without receiving a confirmation from the second general? (I can expand my answer to talk about the other paradox as well, but I think that once you stop being confused about the generals paradox, your question will be resolved.)

Comment: For "*each general made his decision to attack when he sent his first message*", I perhaps should have said a *commitment* to attack.  The final decision is made just before attack time, based on those initial mutually-known commitments and the lack of any message indicating otherwise.  The number of messages exchanged before the final moment is irrelevant, so long as both are aware of the exact time and neither has said anything to reject that time.  It's not really a decision to attack, but simply a realization that there is no reason not to attack as scheduled.

Comment: Suppose I send you a message saying "let's have lunch Sunday at noon" and you reply "okay".  During the week we send each other several other messages about other topics, occasionally mentioning the scheduled meeting  Come Sunday morning, neither of us will be counting  "k"s or thinking "the other person might not show up so I won't bother going".  We'll just go, remembering what we agreed and that neither of us said anything in the meantime to make us think the other person might not show up.  Other than the severity of a single no-show, how is that different from the Generals' situation?

Comment: Okay, but if I send you a message saying "let's have lunch Sunday at noon" and I don't reply at all, you will probably not show up. Similarly, if I reply "okay" and don't hear from you again, I might show up just because unlike the generals I won't die if you don't show up, but I will be prepared for the possibility that you didn't get my message and won't show up yourself.

Comment: Exactly.  If we haven't confirmed with each other, we'll cancel.  But on Sunday morning, if we *have* received several non-cancelling messages from each other, we can both be sure that we both agreed to the meeting, and we won't have any of those doubts.  And in reality, if you didn't reply to my first message, I'd ask you about it again, and if I didn't acknowledge your message, you'd resend your message.  Either communication between us would completely stop, or we would be completely confident in going to the meeting.

Comment: This seems like a highly unproductive discussion. You are only considering cases such as "communication is disrupted immediately" and "lots of messages are exchanged" but the whole point of the paradox is that there must be a boundary between these somewhere, and undesirable behavior happens only at that boundary.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely getting away from my original question, which is why the Two Generals is considered significantly different from the Unexpected Hanging.